# How can I setup AspectJ for a non-Spring Java 11 app built with Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, aspectj, freefair-aspectj

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get some AspectJ advice to run.

### Current Setup

- Java 11
- Gradle 8.3
- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate
- **NOT** using Spring

### Attempted Config (one attempt among many)

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id "io.freefair.aspectj" version "8.3"
}
dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver
    implementation group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.9.20.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt
    implementation group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.9.20.1'
}
```

### Sample Aspect

`LogExecutionTime.java`

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface LogExecutionTime {}
```

`LogExecutionTimeAspect.java`

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class LogExecutionTimeAspect {
    @Around("@annotation(LogExecutionTime)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object proceed = pjp.proceed();
        long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println(pjp.getSignature() + " executed in " + executionTime + "ms");
        return proceed;
    }
}
```

`TestClass.java`

```
public class TestClass {
    @LogExecutionTime
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I've called `new TestClass().hello()` in both a unit test (JUnit 5) and when running our application locally (Appengine Web App). Everything compiles and runs, but the execution time isn't getting printed out. I've tried debugging and putting a break point inside the `LogExecutionTimeAspect::around` method, but it was never reached.

I feel like it shouldn't be this complicated, but I can't seem to figure it out.

### Update

I have a basic working project here for anyone interested: https://github.com/MuffinTheMan/gradle-aspectj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, this works. Did you really forget the `java` plugin, or did you post an incomplete Gradle build file? What I cannot know is if your annotation is in the exact same package as the aspect, otherwise you would need a fully qualified class name in the `@annotation()` pointcut.

```java
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id "io.freefair.aspectj" version "8.3"
}

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.20.1'
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q77174865;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface LogExecutionTime {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q77174865;

public class TestClass {
  @LogExecutionTime
  public String hello() {
    return "hello";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestClass().hello();
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q77174865;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class LogExecutionTimeAspect {
  @Around("@annotation(LogExecutionTime)")
  public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Object proceed = pjp.proceed();
    long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.println(pjp.getSignature() + " executed in " + executionTime + "ms");
    return proceed;
  }
}
```

Running from my IDE IntelliJ IDEA, the console log looks as follows:

```
13:24:24: Executing ':TestClass.main()'...

> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileAspectj
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes

> Task :TestClass.main()
String de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q77174865.TestClass.hello() executed in 0ms
String de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q77174865.TestClass.hello() executed in 2ms
(...)
```

Of course, you see two log messages, because your pointcut captures both `call()` and `execution()` joinpoints. You can fix that as follows:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q77174865;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class LogExecutionTimeAspect {
  @Around("@annotation(LogExecutionTime) && execution(* *(..))")
  public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
      return pjp.proceed();
    } finally {
      System.out.println(pjp.getSignature() + " executed in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
    }
  }
}
```

One thing you maybe forgot is that for Freefair, the default source directory is `src/man/aspectj`. For me, it looks like this:

[image: IDE screenshot showing directory tree]

The default will probably change to `src/main/java` in version 8.4, see [GitHub issue #881](https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/issues/881).

---

**Update 2023-10-10:** Freefair 8.4 has been published and now defaults to `src/main/java`, i.e. it works as expected with a standard directory layout, just like with AspectJ Maven.

Comment: I'm going to test this out, but it appears I had at least two issues based on your answer and reading more documentation from freefair: 1) I didn't realize the default src directory was `src/main/aspectj` and 2) I'm using Lombok, so it appears I should be using the post-compile weaving. I'll give this a shot and report back--thanks!

Comment: **Update:** Freefair 8.4 now defaults to `src/main/java`, i.e. it works as expected with a standard directory layout, just like with AspectJ Maven.

Comment: Ok, so I have a working Java application (that even includes Lombok): https://github.com/MuffinTheMan/gradle-aspectj

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried doing the same configuration in my other application, and it doesn't work--I must have some other conflict (our other application is quite complex, and I can't share the build.gradle here).

Comment: Good to know, that it works for you in the simple project. If you can strip down the complexproject into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by removing step by step as much as possible from the sources and build config, until only a minimal skeleton reproducing your problem remains, you could then anonymise it and share it on GitHub. This is called an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and not only the best option to get help, but you might also learn something about your problem - maybe even enough to solve it by yourself.